# Causation in Mathematics

Tags: logic

I was a student College of Social Science before, but now moved to Mathematics major.

What is the most peculiar point of Mathematics compared social science - especially my ex-major International Relations Studies, there's no causational thinking. I has always been wondered how much it is correct so called causational thinking.

Is there any causational thinking in Mathematics too?

Comment: What do you mean by "causational thinking"?

Comment: You may want to look at the work of Judea Pearl, e.g., *Causal Inference in Statistics*.